# Threads Synchronization using Semaphore

Tags: c, semaphore

I have a problem with my code. Basically, I try to do threading using semaphore but the expected output is wrong. I would like to get a help for my problem.
The scenario is thread **train** simulates the train which uses 1 second to cross the road and a new train will arrive every 5 seconds.Thread **traffic** simulates the car traffic. A 1 second sleep is added into this thread to prevent the infinite *while* loop from running to fast.

```
sem_t gate;
void* train(void* arg){ 

while(1){

    printf("\n The railway gate is closed\n"); 

    //critical section 
    printf("\n The train is crossing\n");
    sleep(1);   //train crossing for 1 second

    printf("\n The railway gate is opened\n");      
    sem_post(&gate); // unlock signal
    sleep(5);   //the next train will arrive every 5 seconds
}
} 
void* car(void* arg) { 
while(1){
    sem_wait(&gate);
    printf("\n The cars are crossing the railway\n");
    sleep(1);                       
}} 


 int main() 
 { 
  //these values are used to identify thread number
int thread0_id=0, thread1_id=1; 

sem_init(&gate, 1, 1);

pthread_t t0,t1; 

//create three threads, passing thread number as the forth argument
pthread_create(&t0,NULL,car,&thread0_id); 
pthread_create(&t1,NULL,train,&thread1_id); 

//join two threads after they finished running
pthread_join(t0,NULL); 
pthread_join(t1,NULL); 
sem_destroy(&gate);
return 0; 
}
```

This the output result I get.

[image]

This is the result I try to achieve.

[image]

Comment: What behavior do you expect? And how does the behavior that you observe differ from your expectation?

Comment: @Giel The thread train simulates the train which uses 1 second to cross the road and a new train will arrive every 5 seconds.Thread traffic simulates the car traffic. So once the "The railway gate is open" five car crossing the railway. As you can see from the image result that I try to achieve. Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Accidental synchronization, both threads sleep by the same amount.  If you want more cars then car() needs to sleep less.  Favor rand().

Comment: @HansPassant in what situation should I use rand() ?

Comment: It is a decent way to avoid accidental synchronization.  Which is dangerous, you might have a threading race bug and never notice.  And it models real life pretty well, trains arrive at a crossing at predictable times but cars don't.